# How to batch upload images and generate multiple images

Tags: 7, media, files

I am planning my new website with Drupal 7. The site will have two core features: blog and photos. Blog is no problem and for photos I know how to implement most of my requirements. Except one ;-)

I plan to add a content-type "Photos" (or "Media"). Each photo will be stored in its content. These contents are categorized using a taxonomy so each photo can be in multiple terms (aka albums). For example a whale can be in "Underwater", "Big-fish" and "Salt water". Views with contextual filters will render the "album"-views etc. So far no problem.

What we don't know how to do yet is bulk-upload of images. Any idea would be great. If there is a gallery module or profile that handles that taxonomy thing / dynamic albums it would be an option to.

Idea: Maybe I can define a "Bulk-Upload" content type which is for uploads only. This conent-type has an "image" field set to "unlimited". When creating such a content a Rule will be triggered which creates multiple "Images" contents for it and deletes the "Bulk-Upload" content afterwards. ...sounds possible but a little tricky.

Any ideas?

Thanks and cheers,
Marc

Comment: I would check out the Feeds Module (http://drupal.org/project/feeds). It can create nodes from remote data files, streams, feeds, etc.

Comment: Thx for the hint to Feeds. Sounds interesting but I don't see how I should feed it with my local images / zip file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload more than one image to a field you can change the number of values the field will accept:

[image: number of values]

To get a photo album configuration you could also look at the [node_gallery](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_gallery) module, or roll your own arrangement.

The [plupload](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload) module will allow you to select multiple images to be uploaded into a single field through one upload process.